# Can I use Access VBA to determine if a table has a Data Macro?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-data-macro

Is there a way to determine via VBA if an Access table contains a data macro or not? I have data macros on *most* of my tables, but my code fails if it encounters a table without it.

I don't receive an error message. Instead, the code keeps running as if it is in an infinite loop, but I have to force Access to quit to escape.

Specifically, I'm trying to save all of my tables and the data macros so I can use the (undocumented) LoadFromText function to recreate them later.

I've highlighted the problem in my code sample, below, with ** BUG **.

```
For Each td In db.TableDefs 
    If Left(td.Name, 4) <> "MSys" Then

        'Save the table as a text file.        
        DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , td.Name, sExportLocation & "Table_" & td.Name & ".txt", True

        'Save the table's data macro as an XML file. 
        '** BUG **: If a table doesn't have a data macro, Access freezes/starts infinite loop.
        Application.SaveAsText acTableDataMacro, td.Name, sExportLocation & "Table_" & td.Name & "_DataMacro.xml"

    End If
Next td
```

I assume that I want some sort of nested If statement that first checks if a data macro exists in the table. I'm not sure how to write that, though.

Thanks to the folks who pointed out the SaveAsText and LoadFromText functions [in another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206153/how-to-export-access-2010-data-macros). These functions seem to have a lot of potential.

Comment: If I execute SaveAsText() on a table with no DataMacros, I get Run-time error '2950', "Reserved Error".  The code snippet apparently is not complete because it doesn't have all variable declarations, etc.  Perhaps your error handling is not set correctly / optimally.  I suggest adding an explicit 'On Error Goto 0' and run the code from a single sub procedure executed from the Immediate window.

Comment: It is worth noting further that I am running Access with MS Office Pro Plus 2013 with VBA 7.1 and MS Office Pro 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple query to indicate if a table has a data macro:

```
SELECT [Name] FROM MSysObjects WHERE Not IsNull(LvExtra) and Type =1
```

This macro could be applied to the VBA code in the question as follows:

```
For Each td In db.TableDefs
    If Left(td.Name, 4) <> "MSys" Then

        'Save the table as a text file.
        DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , td.Name, sExportLocation & _
            "Table_" & td.Name & ".txt", True

        'Define a recordset to determine if the table has a data macro.
        sql = "SELECT [Name] FROM MSysObjects WHERE Not IsNull(LvExtra) and " & _
            "Type = 1 and [Name] = '" & td.Name & "'"
        Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(sql, dbOpenSnapshot)

        'If the table has a data macro, save the data macro as an XML file.
        If rst.RecordCount <> 0 Then
            Application.SaveAsText acTableDataMacro, td.Name, sExportLocation & _
                "Table_" & td.Name & "_DataMacro.xml"
        End If

        'Close the recordset and clear its variable.
        If Not rst Is Nothing Then
            rst.Close
            Set rst = Nothing
        End If

    End If
Next td
```

Credit goes to [a post on UtterAccess](http://www.utteraccess.com/wiki/index.php/Document_Data_Macros) and [@Scotch's answer to a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16244608/how-to-list-datamacro-objects-in-an-access-database) that referenced the UtterAccess post.

Comment: I should add the disclaimer that I cannot find any official or unofficial documentation that explains what the LvExtra field contains. Within Access, the field only displays "Long Binary Data."

Answer (score 0):

To see is database contain macros or not you can use documented methods from DAO. Here is modified example from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff191764.aspx:

```
Sub ContainerObjectX()

 Dim dbsNorthwind As Database
 Dim ctrLoop As Container
 Dim prpLoop As Property
 Dim docItem As Document

 '  Set dbsNorthwind = OpenDatabase("Northwind.mdb")
 Set dbsNorthwind = CurrentDb

 With dbsNorthwind

 ' Enumerate Containers collection.
 For Each ctrLoop In .Containers
    Debug.Print "Properties of " & ctrLoop.Name _
    & " container"

    ' Enumerate Properties collection of each
    ' Container object.
    For Each prpLoop In ctrLoop.Properties
       Debug.Print " " & prpLoop.Name _
           & " = "; prpLoop
    Next prpLoop

    For Each docItem In ctrLoop.Documents
       Debug.Print " docItem.Name = "; docItem.Name
    Next docItem
 Next ctrLoop

 .Close
 End With

End Sub
```

So just you need check documents under "Scripts" container.

My original answer:
I think you can use ExportXML and ImportXML it much more powerful and able do export and import all access objects. 
Example:

```
ExportXML acExportTable, "tblMain", CM_GetDBPath() & "AccessFunc_Tbl.xml" _  
, CM_GetDBPath() & "AccessFunc_TblShema.xml", CM_GetDBPath() & "AccessFunc_Tbl.xsl" _  
, "Images", , acEmbedSchema

....

ImportXML CM_GetDBPath() & "AccessFunc_Tbl.xml", acAppendData
```

Full example is here: http://5codelines.net/wp-content/uploads/xml_1_sampe.rar

Also you can use ADODB library.

```
Public Function EportTblToXml(ByVal imTblFrom As String _  
                             , ByVal imFileTo As String)  
    Dim rstData As ADODB.Recordset  
    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection                 

    Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection  
    Set rstData = New ADODB.Recordset       

    rstData.Open "SELECT * FROM " & imTblFrom, cnn _  
                     , adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic  
    Call SaveRstToXml(rstData, imFileTo)  
    rstData.Close  
End Function  

Public Function LoadXmlToRst(ByVal stFileName As String) As ADODB.Recordset  
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset  
    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset       

    rst.Open stFileName
    Set LoadXmlToRst = rst  
End Function
```

Comment: Your post is interesting, but I don't think it answers my question. Could you explain how `ExportXML` and `ImportXML` will handle a table's *data macros*? For example, if I export or import a table as XML, should I be able to include the table's data macros? If so, how? I experimented with it, and I wasn't able to include that (meta)data.

Comment: Sorry, i mixed your question. I thought that you need extract data.

Comment: Added some notes to my original answer. I hope it will help.

Comment: You can only see regular macros using the CurrentDB.Containers("Scripts").Documents collection.   Likewise, CurrentProject.AllMacros will also only show the regular macros.  Neither of these show data macros.